# Create Cashier subscriptions for testing

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

how do you guys go about creating test users with a Stripe subscription for testing with PHPUnit? Preferably without hitting the Stripe API. Any package tips or general recommendations would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Test them as everything else:

1. [Create mocks](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects) of their API.
2. There is an example of testing [API Client TDD with Mocked Responses](http://www.sitepoint.com/api-client-tdd-mocked-responses/).
3. You can even discover [how does Stripe test itself](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/tree/master/tests)